# Generic UITableViewCell with different type of data

Tags: swift, uitableview, generics

Data keys change for different types and I want to use just this tableview cell for different types. I don't want to create new tableview cell for each type. Is it possible? I guess I should use generics but how can I implement for this problem?

I have a custom UITableViewCell that includes

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var departmentLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var genderLabel: UILabel!
```

`{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "employee",
      "data": {
        "name": "Michael",
        "department": "HR",
        "gender": "Male"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "employer",
      "data": {
        "name": "Julia",
        "division": "Finance",
        "sex": "Female"
      }
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: It is possible. Decode `data` (the inner `data`) as `[String:String]` or – more sophisticated – declare `data` as enum with associated types.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question, you want data that takes different forms but returned in the same array to be representable in a single table view cell. This is definitely doable, the challenge being parsing the variable JSON response into something consistent that you can send to your cells to be displayed.

This sort of thing would be possible using a custom implmentation of `Codable`. The caveat being that you'll need to know what sort of options this data could be coming down in (ie will gender always be either 'sex' or 'gender'?)

An example would be:

```
struct CompanyPersonContainer: Decodable {
    var data: [CompanyRelatedPerson]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        data = []

        if var dataContainer = try? values.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: CodingKeys.data) {
            while !(dataContainer.isAtEnd) {
                let companyPerson: CompanyRelatedPerson

                if let employee = try dataContainer.decodeIfPresent(Employee.self) {
                    companyPerson = employee
                } else if let employer = try dataContainer.decodeIfPresent(Employer.self) {
                    companyPerson = employer
                } else {
                    fatalError() // You need to know the total possible values you'll be decoding
                }

                data.append(companyPerson)
            }
        }
    }
}

protocol CompanyRelatedPerson: Codable  {
    var name: String { get set }
    var department: String { get set }
    var gender: String { get set }
}

struct Employee: Codable, CompanyRelatedPerson {
    var name: String
    var department: String
    var gender: String
}

struct Employer: Codable, CompanyRelatedPerson {
    var name: String
    var department: String
    var gender: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case department = "division"
        case gender = "sex"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a protocol `ViewModel` then create different view models who inherit this protocol.

```swift
protocol ViewModel {
    var name: String { get set }
    var department: String { get set }
    var gender: String { get set }
}

struct EmployeeViewModel: ViewModel {
   var name: String
   var department: String
   var gender: String

   // Suppose you already have this data model from data.
   init(employee: Employee) {
      self.name = employee.name
      self.department = employee.department
      self.gender = employee.gender
   }
}

struct Employer: ViewModel {
   var name: String
   var department: String
   var gender: String

   init(employer: Employer) {
       self.name = employer.name
       self.department = employer.division
       self.gender = employer.sex
   }
}
```

Then, create a function in your tableview cell to assign the values to your properties.

```swift
// In your table view cell
func setViewModel(_ viewModel: ViewModel) {
    self.nameLabel.text = vm.name
    // do the same for the rest of labels...
}
```

For me, the advantage of using a protocol view model is that you can pass any view models inherited from protocol to your view to assign the value, that avoids to expose your data in your view (tableview cell in this case).